# Is there a way for a user inside a domain to reset their password by themselves without contacting the administrator

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2016

Everytime a user has problem with their password they have to contact the administrator to reset the password for them.

Is there a way or a policy that provide the ability to reset their password without contacting the admin, by using for example OTP?

Comment: There are many products that do this. Azure also has a self-service password reset portal.

Comment: Under default settings, and without a 3rd party password management solution, the only way a user can reset their own password is from the windows lock screen. For this to work, they must be logged into a domain computer and know the current password. If they forget the password, or cannot access a domain computer to reset an expired password, they must contact an administrator.